# sbt: execute shell command from without splitting it on spaces

Tags: scala, sbt

This one feels like it should be simple, but I cannot seem to get it right.

In my project configuration in `build.sbt` I need to call `make` with an overridden variable. Don't ask me why, there is no way around this.

The problem is, that the value of the overridden variable contains a space. Despite the fact that the command works perfectly from shell directly, it fails from sbt. I suspect this is because whatever starts the process splits the command by spaces and feeds them directly into the process in a list of arguments, which does not preserve soundness.

This is an approximate excerpt from my `build.sbt` file:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    Compile / sourceGenerators += Def.task {

      val extraClasspath = "-cp dependency.jar"
      val command: String = s"make JAVAC_FLAGS='$extraClasspath'"
      println(s"Running:\n$command")
      command !

      Seq.empty // obviously I generate some sources but that's not important

    }
  )
```

The result is, frankly, quite silly:

```
Running:
make JAVAC_FLAGS='-cp dependency.jar'
make: *** No rule to make target 'dependency.jar''
```

I think somewhere along the way a process is started with the arguments

```
make
JAVAC_FLAGS='-cp
dependency.jar'
```

and I have no idea how to get around it.

Answer (score 2):

SBT uses a [Process API](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Process.html).

Creating a `Process` explicitly should let you define the command as expected.

Not tested but I'd try:

```scala
Process(Seq("make", "JAVAC_FLAGS='-cp dependency.jar'"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a step in the right direction. I realize now, that for my specific case, I can use the Process API to set the CLASSPATH environment variable and everything works well. However, this is specific to my use case and I would like to see this whole problem solved. Your solution does not work. It results in the execution of `javac '-cp dependency.jar'` which is incorrect, because `-cp dependency.jar` is not a `javac` option; so this results in an error.

Comment: This is a matter of the Makefile or make command then. If you were to run it manually (outside of SBT), how would you run the `make` command?

Comment: I would run `make JAVAC_FLAGS='-cp dependency.jar'`. This calls `javac -cp dependency.jar`. I even tested this in a very small example. If my Makefile has variable `VAR=normal` and goal `all` with recipe `echo $(VAR)` or `echo ${VAR}`, then calling `make` results in the execution of `echo normal`. But if I instead execute `make VAR='overridden with space'`, this results in the execution of `echo overridden with space`, as expected. I strongly believe this is actually the minimal reproducible example we need to consider and that it is loyal to the nature of the original post.

Comment: This doesn't look like "a matter of the Makefile or make comman". Here, take a look: https://imgur.com/a/D4srExQ